# @SQLDelete does not propagate to child table

Tags: hibernate

I want to implement soft delete using Spring JPA + hibernate. Suppose I have a material_group table which has one-to-many relationship with material_master table. In my mysql database I have restricted the deletion of the parent record if child record exists.

in material_group and material_master entity I have used the following

```
@SQLDelete(sql="update material_group set delete_ind='Y' where material_grp_id = ?")
```

AND

```
@SQLDelete(sql="update material_master set delete_ind='Y' where material_id = ?")
```

I can achieve one scenario i.e. material_group can be soft deleted if there is **NO** material.

But I want to restrict the soft delete of parent if the child records exist. However, it **allows** the soft delete of parent table without any change in the child entry. Any idea is appreciated to achieve this use case. (Programmatic approach is my last choice)

Code snippet is given below
**material_group table**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="material_group")
    @NamedQuery(name="MaterialGroup.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM MaterialGroup m")
    @SQLDelete(sql="update material_group set delete_ind='Y' where material_grp_id = ?")
    @Where(clause="delete_ind is NULL")
    public class MaterialGroup implements Serializable {

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="materialGroup", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
        @Where(clause="delete_ind is NULL")
        private List<MaterialMaster> materialMasters;

    }
```

**material_master table**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="material_master")
    @NamedQuery(name="MaterialMaster.findAll", query="SELECT m FROM MaterialMaster m")
    @SQLDelete(sql="update material_master set delete_ind='Y' where material_id = ?")
    @Where(clause="delete_ind is NULL")
    public class MaterialMaster implements Serializable {
        //bi-directional many-to-one association to MaterialGroup
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="material_grp_id")
        private MaterialGroup materialGroup;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your parent object, add this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = MaterialGroup.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "YOUR_FOREIGN_KEY_COLUMN", nullable = false, 
insertable = false)
private Set<MaterialMaster> materialMaster = new HashSet<MaterialMaster> 
();
```

After that it should work if other specs are right.